# Why is this tuple ambiguous without more context in swift 3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tuples

After reviewing code that worked a few months ago, can some explain how to fix this error? The error that shows says "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context".

```
var products = [("Kayak","A boat for one person","Watersports",275.0,10),
                ("Lifejacket","Protective and fashionable","Watersports",48.95,14),
                ("Soccer Ball","FIFA-approved size and weight","Soccer",19.5,32),
                ("Corner Flags","Give your playing field a professional touch","Soccer",34.95,1),
                ("Stadium","Flat-packed 35,000-seat stadium","Soccer",79500.0,4),
                ("Improve your brain efficiency by 75%","Chess",16.0,8),
                ("Unsteady Chair","Secretly give your opponent a disadvantage","Chess",29.95,3),
                ("Human Chess Board","A fun game for the family","Chess",75.0,2),
                ("Bling-Bling King","Gold-plated,diamon-studded King","Chess",1200.0,4)]
```

Comment: A common procedure to find the cause of "strange error messages" is to remove lines until the problem vanishes, and then add lines again, in order to isolate the problem. You could easily do that yourself ...

Comment: When the built-in type inference fails, I prefer explicitly stating the type and seeing if the error goes away. If it doesn't, that's good evidence that the type wasn't actually ambiguous, but simply wrong (or at least, not what you thought it was).

Comment: Be kind to your compiler.  Don't give it big initial values without telling it the type:  `var products: [(String, String, String, Double, Int)] = [...`.  Had you done this, it would have told you `error: cannot convert value of type '(String, String, Double, Int)' to expected element type '(String, String, String, Double, Int)'` and pointed out the exact line with the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line :

`("Improve your brain efficiency by 75%","Chess",16.0,8),`

only has 2 strings instead of 3. The name of the activity (?) seems to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't abuse Structs like this. You should refactor this into a struct:

```
struct Product { //fill these names in better
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let category: String
    let price: Double
    let x: Int
}

var products = [
    Product(name: "Kayak",
        description: "A boat for one person",
        category: "Watersports", price: 275.0, x: 10),
    Product(name: "Lifejacket",
        description: "Protective and fashionable",
        category: "Watersports", price: 48.95, x: 14),
    Product(name: "Soccer Ball",
        description: "FIFA-approved size and weight",
        category: "Soccer", price: 19.5, x: 32),
    Product(name: "Corner Flags",
        description: "Give your playing field a professional touch",
        category: "Soccer", price: 34.95, x: 1),
    Product(name: "Stadium",
        description: "Flat-packed 35,000-seat stadium",
        category: "Soccer", price: 79500.0, x: 4),
    Product(name: "YOU FORGOT TO GIVE ME A NAME",
        description: "Improve your brain efficiency by 75%",
        category: "Chess", price: 16.0, x: 8),
    Product(name: "Unsteady Chair",
        description: "Secretly give your opponent a disadvantage",
        category: "Chess", price: 29.95, x: 3),
    Product(name: "Human Chess Board",
        description: "A fun game for the family",
        category: "Chess", price: 75.0, x: 2),
    Product(name: "Bling-Bling King",
        description: "Gold-plated,diamon-studded King",
        category: "Chess", price: 1200.0, x: 4)
]
```

This makes it much clearer what all these values are, and makes accessing them much more natural (you can get the name by `product.name`, rather than `product.1`, for example).